# Slow response of function Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I created a function to change users, but after making an HTTP request with this function, sometimes it takes a delay to get the return.

The function runs successfully without any error, but the problem is the delay to get the return of the execution.

**I noticed that does not always occur, after the first call the function runs quickly ... Is there an explanation for this?**

> **Function execution took 8617 ms, finished with status code: 200**
>
> Function execution took 1182 ms, finished with status code: 200
>
> Function execution took 1361 ms, finished with status code: 200
>
> ......

**auth.functions.ts**

```
export const updateUserHttpRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT");
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");

        switch (req.method) {
            case 'PUT': {
                
                admin.auth().updateUser(req.body.id, {
                    displayName: req.body.name,
                    photoURL: req.body.avatar,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password,
                }).then(async (authUserChanged) => {

                    try {

                        
                        const databaseConfig = await firestore.collection(req.body.id).doc('database').get();

                        firestore.collection(req.body.id).doc('database').get();
                        const databaseUrl = databaseConfig.data().url;

                        const pathUsers = `${databaseUrl}/config/users`;

                        await firestore.collection(pathUsers)
                            .doc(req.body.id).update(req.body);

                        res.status(200).send({
                            message: 'User changed success',
                            authUser: authUserChanged
                        });

                        console.info(`User: ${authUserChanged.displayName} 
                                changed success!`, authUserChanged.toJSON());

                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        res.status(500).send(error);
                    }
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.warn(error.errorInfo);
                        res.status(500).send(error.errorInfo);
                        console.log('Error on update user', error);
                    });
            }
                break;
            default:
                res.status(405).send({
                    error: 'Error, method not exist.'
                });
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

**users.effects.ts:**

```
@Effect()
updateUser$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType(usersActions.ActionsTypes.UPDATE).pipe(
        map((action: usersActions.Update) => action),
        switchMap((data) => this.usersService.updateUser(data.payload).pipe(
            map(() => {
                return new usersActions.UpdateSuccess();
            }),
            catchError((res => {
                return of(new usersActions.UpdateError({ error: res.error }));
            }))
        )
        ));
```

**users.service.ts:**

```
updateUser(user: any): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    return this._http.put(this._requestUrl, user, this._httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: The warning message about dates should have nothing to do with the speed at which your code runs.  They're almost certainly unrelated.

Comment: Surely I think this, but I put it to record the information of this occurrence ... I believe it has to do with the code relatively.